# What does 'the need' mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs, nouns

In the sentence below...

> Scarcity and the need to economize.

1. What does the noun 'the Need' mean?
2. What does the noun 'the Need to' mean?
3. Why do we put the defined article *the* before the noun *Need*?

[image]
Thanks for help.

Comment: Please notice that "scarcity and the need to economize" is not a sentence, but just a phrase. It could be the title of a book, or a headline -- as seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your first question. Have you looked up the word *need* in a dictionary? If so, what part of the definition doesn't make sense? From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/need)

> 4 - necessity arising from the circumstances of a situation or case:
>   *There is no need to worry.* 
>   6 - a condition marked by the lack of something requisite:
>   *the need for leadership.*

In your second question, "What does the noun 'the Need to' mean?" you have mistaken the "to" for being part of the noun. In reality, it is part of the verb, "**to economize**." Any time you see "to" immediately before a verb, it indicates the infinitive, or unconjugated form of the verb. "The need to economize" is a noun phrase.

We put the definite article, "the," before the noun to indicate that it actually is a noun. If it said "scarcity and need to economize," then *need* becomes a plural verb. For instance, consider these example sentences with and without the article,

> The government has to deal with scarcity and **the need** to economize
>   Local governments are facing scarcity and **need** to economize.

The first one uses "the need" as a noun while the second one uses "need" as a verb.

Comment: @StephenC Good answer, Stephen. I'd only add that abstract nouns like "need" are not always complemented by "to"-infinitives. In fact, "need" takes "for" when what follows is another noun, as in the example you gave further above ("need **for** leadership"). Other abstract nouns may be complemented by "of"- (or other prepositional) phrases ("likekihood **of** economic success"),  or by "that"- clauses ("the belief **that** they need to economize")